# Call AWS Batch meter Generic API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, generics

I have to call AWS batch meter API which is generic. When I am calling this function I am getting an error. Please help how to call a generic API

```
public <T> Optional<T> getValueForField(String fieldName, Class<T> clazz) {
        byte var4 = -1;
        switch(fieldName.hashCode()) {
        case -1532767274:
            if (fieldName.equals("Results")) {
                var4 = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 743387085:
            if (fieldName.equals("UnprocessedRecords")) {
                var4 = 1;
            }
        }

        switch(var4) {
        case 0:
            return Optional.ofNullable(clazz.cast(this.results()));
        case 1:
            return Optional.ofNullable(clazz.cast(this.unprocessedRecords()));
        default:
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

public List<UsageRecordResult> results() {
        return this.results;
    }
```

Calling Above API

```
batchMeterUsageResponse.getValueForField(RESULT, (Class<List<UsageRecordResult>>) new ArrayList<>().getClass());
```

Error i am getting :

```
Error:(98, 175) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.util.ArrayList> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<java.util.List<software.amazon.awssdk.services.marketplacemetering.model.UsageRecordResult>>
```

Comment: Is _`batchMeterUsageResponse.getValueForField()`_ a method that you wrote? Or is it a library method from this *AWS batch meter API*? Either way, what is the intention/expectation of _`clazz.cast(this.results())`_ — to the best of your understanding? And then after you answer that question, my next question is: *Why is it done like that?*

Comment: batchMeterUsageResponse.getValueForField() this is a library methhod provieded by batch meter API

Comment: „*...batchMeterUsageResponse.getValueForField() this is a library methhod provieded by batch meter AP...*“ — Thank you Sir. That answered ***Q*** (***1***). There were two more questions: (***2***)  *what is the intention/expectation of `clazz.cast(this.results())`* — *to the best of your understanding?* (***3***) *Why is it done like that?* TIA.

Comment: Dear Sir. Even if you don't accept my answer, for educational reasons I'm very curious to know whether or not [*the solution I proposed*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307337) solves the compilation error you reported. More important than my own curiosity, your feedback (***any** feedback*) will be a service to the entire community. It might solve somebody else's similar problem in the future. TIA.

Comment: i have use batchMeterUsageResponse.result() instead of batchMeterUsageResponse.getValueForField()

Comment: „*...i have use batchMeterUsageResponse.result() instead...*“ — That's great! Thanks for finally getting back to me. But I'm still curious to know the answers to the questions I asked you. Please? If you don't know the answers, then OK. But at least can you share a link to a Batch Meter API coding example? A tutorial? Anything? Any Java source code example that demonstrates how to use _`batchMeterUsageResponse.result()`_? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR*** — If my assumption about the intention of your code is correct, then [*the simplest solution is demonstrated here*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307337)…

```
...
Optional< List > wtTF = batchMeterUsageResponse.getValueForField( RESULTS, List.class );
...
```

To execute the code shown above, click the green ***Start*** button [*at the top of this IDE*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307337).

---

***The long answer***

[*`BatchMeterUsageResult`*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/marketplacemetering/model/BatchMeterUsageResult.html) has a [*`getResults()`*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/marketplacemetering/model/BatchMeterUsageResult.html#getResults--) method and a [*`getUnprocessedRecords()`*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/marketplacemetering/model/BatchMeterUsageResult.html#getUnprocessedRecords--) method that look like the same methods you have in your question. So my proposed fix above assumes that the intention of your sample code, is to return either a *`List<UsageRecordResult>`* or a *`List<UsageRecord>`*; depending on the value of *`fieldName.hashCode`*.

> „*Error i am getting :*“

> ```
> Error:(98, 175) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.util.ArrayList> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<java.util.List<software.amazon.awssdk.services.marketplacemetering.model.UsageRecordResult>>
> ```

The error message is telling you that your attempt to cast from one type of *`Class<List<E>>`* to a different type of *`Class<List<E>>`*, failed.

The compiler knows the *`Class`* type of *`new ArrayList<>().getClass()`* to be *`Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.util.ArrayList>`*. You are trying to cast that to *`Class<List<UsageRecordResult>>`*.

The compiler cannot do the conversion because the two *`Class`* types are incompatible. The *underlying* reason they are incompatible is because *`List<UsageRecordResult>`* does not meet the criteria of: *`extends java.util.ArrayList`*. Remember: The interface *`List<E>`* is the *superclass* of *`ArrayList<E>`*. And as you know, it's impossible to assign a superclass to a subclass.

But that's only the first part of the problem with your code. The details of the other problems probably won't be as interesting to you as the above solution to make your code compile.

If my assumption about your code's intention is incorrect, then please edit your question with a clearer explanation of the actual intention of your code? TIA.