# Java generics: Map nested json response to Java objects

Tags: java, generics

Scenario:
I'm working with an unusual external API in which every attribute is a map with multiple values.
In order to convert this response into simple Java objects, I had to do some dirty unboxing. Below is one of the typical java class. As you can see how I'm unboxing data from response and mapping them to my java class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.my.util.BaseUtil.unbox;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PartyDetailsDto {

    private String partyId;
    private String partyType;
    private String title;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @JsonProperty(value = "partyId")
    public void unboxPartyId(Map<String, String> data) {
        this.partyId = unbox(data, "evidenceId");
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "partyType")
    public void unboxPartyType(Map<String, String> partyType) {
        this.partyType = unbox(partyType, "value");
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "individual")
    public void unboxIndividualDetails(Map<String, Object> individual) {
        Map<String, String> title = (Map<String, String>) individual.get("title");
        Map<String, String> firstName = (Map<String, String>) individual.get("firstName");
        Map<String, String> lastName = (Map<String, String>) individual.get("lastName");
        Map<String, String> middleName = (Map<String, String>) individual.get("middleName");
        Map<String, String> dateOfBirth = (Map<String, String>) individual.get("birthDate");

        this.title = unbox(title, "value");
        this.firstName = unbox(firstName, "value");
        this.lastName = unbox(lastName, "value");
        this.middleName = unbox(middleName, "value");
        this.dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(unbox(dateOfBirth, "value"));
    }
}
```

This is the sample util method - `unbox` - which I've created in order to avoid writing such ugly code. Right now, it only works for cases where String is returned.

```
import java.util.Map;

public class BaseUtil {
    // TODO: Make this method generic
    public static String unbox(Map<String, String> data, String key) {
        if (data != null && data.containsKey(key)) {
            return data.get(key);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert above method into a generic one where I could specify the return type dynamically and cast the returned data accordingly.

Can anyone help me out in creating one?

I've tried this:

```
public static <T> T unbox(Map<String, String> data, String key, Class<T> type) {
        if (data != null && data.containsKey(key)) {
            return (type) data.get(key);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But it obviously doesn't work but in theory that's the kind of solution that I'm expecting.

EDIT: Here's a sample input of complex type:

```
// The associatePartyRole is a list of Stings.
@JsonProperty(value = "associatedPartyRole")
public void unboxAssociatedPartyRole(Map<String, Object> data) {
    this.associatedPartyRole = unbox(data, "value", List.class); 

    // Compilation error: Need list, provided object.
}
```

**EDIT 2: Here's the final solution:**
**PartyDetailsDto.java**

```
public class PartyDetailsDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3851075484507637508L;

    private String partyId;
    private String partyType;
    private String title;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @JsonProperty(value = "partyId")
    public void unboxPartyId(Map<String, String> data) {
        this.partyId = unbox(data, "evidenceId");
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "partyType")
    public void unboxPartyType(Map<String, String> partyType) {
        this.partyType = unbox(partyType, "value");
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "individual")
    public void unboxIndividualDetails(Map<String, Object> individual) {
        this.title = unbox(unbox(individual, "title", Map.class), "value");
        this.firstName = unbox(unbox(individual, "firstName", Map.class), "value");
        this.lastName = unbox(unbox(individual, "lastName", Map.class), "value");
        this.middleName = unbox(unbox(individual, "middleName", Map.class), "value");
        this.dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(unbox(unbox(individual, "title", Map.class), "value"));
    }
}
```

**BaseUtil.java**

```
public class BaseLineUtil {
    public static <T> T unbox(Map<String, Object> data, String key, Class<?> ofType) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(data)
                .map(m -> (T) ofType.cast(m.get(key)))
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public static <T> T unbox(Map<String, T> data, String key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(data)
                .map(m -> (T) m.get(key))
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Thanks @deduper @davidxxx for your answers.

Comment: @saran3h Is your use case that you do not know the value-type of the `Map`, i.e. that you have a `Map<String, ?>` or a `Map<String, Object>`, from which you want to extract values of certain types?

Comment: A remark: the existance-check for a key of a `Map` is superfluous since [a `Map` will return null if no mapping for the key exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Brilliant, saran3h! Glad it works! — „*...I'm working with an unusual external API...*“ — Would you mind if I ask which external API that is? It looks hella interesting. I'm eager to learn more about it. TIA. P.S: I've updated by answer with [*that final iteration's implementation details and results*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307658). Looking forward to your feedback. TIA.

Comment: @saran3h In the second method the cast is not required. The first method is more complex than needed. Why passing a class to cast while only type inferring is needed ? I edited my answer and I explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> „*…I followed [@davidxx's] solution but it doesn't seem to work when the return type is supposed to be a list or an array. How would i handle that case?…*“

Through a process I call „*EDD*“ („[*Experiment-driven Development*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307658)“) the following way to handle those cases emerged…

```
public static < T > T unbox( Map< String, T > data, String key, Class< ? > ofType ) {
    if ( data != null && data.containsKey( key ) ) {
        return (T)ofType.cast( data.get( key ) ) ;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can observe in [*`main(String[])`*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307658) that the following calls successfully return the expected result…

```
...
List< String > unBoxedList = unbox( mapOfLists, foo, List.class );
...
List< ? >[ ] unBoxedArrayOfLists = unbox( mapOfArrayOfLists, "bar", List[ ].class );
... 
String unBoxedString = unbox( mapOfStrings, foo, String.class );
...
Integer unBoxedInteger = unbox( mapOfIntegers, bar, Integer.class );
...
```

Click the green ***Start*** button at the top of the page in the link above, to run the *experiment*.

---

---

After feedback in the comments from @saran3h that clarified his use case, the following refactor emerged from [*a subsequent iteration of the experiment*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307658)…

```
public class BaseUtil {
    
    public List<Object> associatedPartyRole ;
    
    // TODO: Make this method generic
    public static < T > T unbox( Map< String, T > data, String key, Class< ? > ofType ) {
        if ( data != null && data.containsKey( key ) ) {
            return (T)ofType.cast( data.get( key ) ) ;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public void unboxAssociatedPartyRole(Map<String, Object> data) {
        this.associatedPartyRole = (List)unbox(data, "foo", Object.class);        
    }
}
```

That new case was successfully tested with…

```
...
private static final Map<String, Object> mapOfObjects = new HashMap< >( ); 
...
mapOfObjects.put( foo, (Object)mapOfLists.get( foo ) );
...
BaseUtil user = new BaseUtil( );

user.unboxAssociatedPartyRole( mapOfObjects );

List< Object > objs = user.associatedPartyRole;

assertIsA( objs, List.class );
```

Observe the results of running the experiment with the above refactor (*pardon my French*)…

```
[What The Reifiable Fuck@&*%$*!?]
                     EXPERIMENT SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the rationale for the casts in line `return (T)ofType.cast( data.get( key ) ) ;`?  --- A remark: the existance-check for a key of a `Map` is superfluous since [a `Map` will return `null` if no mapping for the key exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: „*...the rationale for the casts?*“ — There are 2 casts there. _`cast(data.get(...))`_ is a nod to [*my friend @BharatWadhawa's Q*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399325/call-aws-batch-meter-generic-api) (*see my „(**2**)“ in his comments*). The _`(T)`_ cast emerged from my *EDD* process: *(**1**) write a failing test*. *(**2**) Do just enuf to make the test pass*; ***but no more***. So, 1st I got an „*incompatible types*“ failure. 2nd The „*simplest thing that **could** possibly work*“ is _`(T)`_. See the API links in my answer's comments and _`Class.cast()`_'s Javadoc for details. HTH

Comment: "***(2)** Do just enuf to make the test pass; **but no more***" - Hmm then you should [forego the casts and the additional `ofType`-parameter alltogether](https://ideone.com/t6V9oO). Which leaves the question what `unbox(...)` actually does aside from a `null`-check. Please correct me if I am wrong. --- I removed the assertions tand threw actual Exceptions since assertion checking must be explicitly enabled. -- A remark: you may want to remove the blanks and commatas from the pattern since those characters will influence the character group.

Comment: „*a Map will return null if no mapping for the key exists*“ — You're preaching to the pulpit, Mein Freund. My policy, *when I answer a question*, is to provide the asker a solution that makes the fewest number of changes to their original code. After all, the OP's question was: „*Can anyone help me out in creating one?*“ and not „*Please will you do a thorough code review of my code?*“. Was it? Your critique, while correct, is immaterial to solving the OP's Q. If you think otherwise, then I suggest you redirect your question to the OP if you believe it will make his original code work. HTH.

Comment: „*Which leaves the question what `unbox(...)` actually does aside from a `null`-check*“ — Why haven't you asked @saran3h that question?

Comment: „*the blanks and commatas from the pattern since those characters will influence the character group*“ — I didn't give that _`Pattern`_ any in-depth thought. But I'm a humble guy, so I'll concede: regular expressions aren't something that I claim to *Know-It-All*. I don't use them everyday. So I was relying on my admittedly less-than-Rain-man-like memory. But in the name of *intellectual honesty*, if you paste in a comment below, a correction for „*the blanks and commatas [sic]*“, then I'll consider changing that 25 char one-liner for you; ***IFF*** it's convincing enuf. Alles klas, Mein Herr?

Comment: The "easy fix" would be [`Pattern.compile("[AEIOU]");`](https://regex101.com/r/FPz7cT/1), though this would also match on an uppercase vowel that is not in first position. I think [`Pattern.compile("^[AEIOU]");`](https://regex101.com/r/FPz7cT/2) should do the job (please double-check).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219908/discussion-between-deduper-and-turing85).

Comment: Interesting, that’s the kind of solution i was looking for. Let me check and get back to you. I had to put the related functionality to hold for a while hence the late reply.

Comment: In my case, the json object which gets mapped to Java looks something like this:
`{
"value": [x,y,z],
"keyA": "---",
"keyB": "123",
"keyC": {...}
}`
So I'm storing it as `Map<String, Object>` (as shown in my question)
In your solution, `mapOfArrayOfLists` is an Object for me and hence gives me compilation errors. A simple cast works perfectly fine though.

Comment: `Which leaves the question what unbox(...) actually does aside from a null-check“`

Just save some lines like this: `unbox(unbox(data, "inner_key", Map.class), "outer_key", String.class)` maybe.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe that :

```
public static <T> T unbox(Map<String, T> data, String key) {
    if (data != null && data.containsKey(key)) {
        return data.get(key);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here `T` implies `T extends Object`.

That you can use so with any class:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = ...;
Integer value = unbox(map, "key");
```

Note that you could simplify your implementation such as :

```
public static <T> T unbox(Map<String, T> data, String key) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(data)
                 .map(m -> m.get(key))
                 .orElse(null);
}
```

It is also more efficient (a single map access)

OP comment :

> I followed your solution but it doesn't seem to work when the return
> type is supposed to be a list or an array. How would i handle that
> case

That is surprising. It should work. Try that sample code :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key", 100);
    Integer value = unbox(map, "key");
    System.out.println(value);

    Map<String, List<Integer>> mapOfList = new HashMap<>();
    mapOfList.put("key", Arrays.asList(1, 2));
    List<Integer> valueList = unbox(mapOfList, "key");
    System.out.println(valueList);

    Map<String, int[]> mapOfArray = new HashMap<>();
    mapOfArray.put("key", new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    int[] valueArray = unbox(mapOfArray, "key");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(valueArray));
  }
```

It outputs :

> 100
>
> [1, 2]
>
> [1, 2, 3]

If that is not what you are looking for. Please rewrite your question by specifying exactly what you want to perform.

---

Edit after requiement change :

```
public void unboxIndividualDetails(Map<String, Object> individual) {...}
```

In fact here you want to perform unsafe casts.  To achieve that you don't need to pass a `Class` instance and that not will not make your code more safe type either.
What you want is telling to the compiler to accept that the object that is declared as `Object` be assigned to a more specific type variable.
In terms of cast logic that looks like :

```
Object o = Integer.valueOf(100);
Integer i = (Integer)o;
```

By declaring a parameterized generic type method, the compiler infers `T` from the target type (the variable type that received the call method return), so you can do just `return (T)myObject`.

Concrete code :

```
public static <T> T unboxUnsafe(Map<String, Object> data, String key) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(data)
                   .map(m -> (T)m.get(key))
                   .orElse(null);
}
```

And here a sample test :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> mapOfObjects = new HashMap< >( );
    mapOfObjects.put("longKey", 1L );
    mapOfObjects.put("stringKey", "hello" );
    Long l = unboxUnsafe(mapOfObjects, "longKey");
    System.out.println(l);
    String s = unboxUnsafe(mapOfObjects, "stringKey");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output :

> 1

> hello

Comment: I would prefer `return data == null ? null : data.get(key)` over creating an `Optional`, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for that. I followed your solution but it doesn't seem to work when the return type is supposed to be a list or an array. 
How would i handle that case?

Comment: davidxxx? You say: „*Here `T` **implies** `T extends Object`*“. But then you say: „*you could* ***simplify***...such as: *`<T extends Object> T unbox(...)`*“. My understanding has always been that when you „*simplify*“ an expression, you're typically ***removing*** some term; not ***adding*** a term that's ***implied*** as already being an inherent part of the expression. Can you help me understand what the benefit is of your explicit _`<T extends Object>`_? TIA.

Comment: @Slaw I agree that form is not bad either.

Comment: @deduper That is just a typo of course. I simplied the logic not that part.

Comment: @saran3h  It should also work. I added an example for each case (single value, list and array)

Comment: „*...That is just a typo of course...*“ — Yes, „*of course*“, @davidxxx. What *else* could it even *possibly* be? ;)

Comment: A remark: the existance-check for a key of a `Map` is superfluous since [a `Map` will return `null` if no mapping for the key exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: The problem really is that I'm storing a json node as: `Map<String, Object>` as every key can have a value that could either be a primitive or of a complex type (including a map itself). When I pass it to `unbox(...)` it just gives me a compilation error because the return type would be `T` ie. Object rather than a List<String/Integer>.

Comment: @Turing85's critique: „*existance-check for a key of a `Map` is blah...*“ — *though technically correct **in general*** — it *may* be based on an assumption that he knows your use case better 'n you. In the absence of details, such jumping to the wrong conclusion happens often in SO. —  „*...a value that could either be a primitive or of a complex type (including a map itself)...*“ — Thx for clarifying your use case @saran3h. — „*I'm storing a json node as: `Map<String, Object>`...*“ — A newer iteration of my experiment tests that use case. Tell me when UR ready? I'll update it for you. TIA.

Comment: „*...the new iteration...*“ — Thanks for getting back, @saran3h. I've [*refactored the experiment*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307658). It now successfully exercises a ***simplified*** _`Map<String, Object>`_ case. The URL of the experiment is the same. But you'll need to close any other session with that project you might have had opened previously. Then relaunch it using the same URL. Please let me know how close (*or how far off*) from your ***original*** request this iteration is? Including specifically: *What **doesn't** it do, that you'd **originally** intended it to do?* Please? TIA.

Comment: @deduper okay it works indeed. However, it looks like i just need 2 different methods to take care of all the cases. Ill edit my post and share the final solution. I will be happy to accept your answer if you could kindly include this last part in it.

Comment: Awesome, @saran3h! Glad I could help. —  „*...kindly include **this last part** in it...*“ — You bet. Except I'm not sure which part is *this last part*. Sorry. Do you mean this part: „*...Ill edit my post and share the final solution...*“? Or this part: „*I've refactored the experiment. It now successfully exercises a simplified `Map<String, Object>` case...*“? Just let me know. TIA.

Comment: @deduper `It now successfully exercises a simplified Map<String, Object> case`: This case.