# Typesafe heterogenous Map using super type tokens

Tags: java, generics

I have additional question about example from https://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html which shows Typesafe Heterogenous Container pattern.

```
public class FavoritesClass {

    private final Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void setFavorite(Class<T> klass, T thing) {
        favorites.put(klass, thing);
    }

    public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> klass) {
        return klass.cast(favorites.get(klass));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FavoritesClass f = new FavoritesClass();
        f.setFavorite(String.class, "Java");
        f.setFavorite(Integer.class, 0xcafebabe);
        String s = f.getFavorite(String.class);
        int i = f.getFavorite(Integer.class);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(i);

        // you simply can't make a type token for a generic type because of erasure
        f.setFavorite(List<String>.class, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

This example shows how to hold various objects in `favorites` `Map` in typesafe way using type token as `Map` key.

It's impossible to use generic types though because of erasure.

I tried to extend example using super type tokens approach (`TypeReference` class) suggested in an article, but I can't make it typesafe.

```
/**
 * References a generic type.
 *
 * @author crazybob@google.com (Bob Lee)
 */
public abstract class TypeReference<T> {

    private final Type type;
    private volatile Constructor<?> constructor;

    protected TypeReference() {
        Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (superclass instanceof Class) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missing type parameter.");
        }
        this.type = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new instance of {@code T} using the default, no-arg
     * constructor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T newInstance()
            throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
                   InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        if (constructor == null) {
            Class<?> rawType = type instanceof Class<?>
                ? (Class<?>) type
                : (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType();
            constructor = rawType.getConstructor();
        }
        return (T) constructor.newInstance();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the referenced type.
     */
    public Type getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

My extended example:

```
public class FavoritesTypeReference {

    private final Map<TypeReference<?>, Object> favorites = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void setFavorite(TypeReference<T> typeReference, T thing) {
        favorites.put(typeReference, thing);
    }

    public <T> void setFavorite(Class<T> klass, T thing) {
        TypeReference<T> typeReference = new TypeReference<T>() {
        };
        favorites.put(typeReference, thing);
    }

    public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> klass) {
        TypeReference<T> typeReference = new TypeReference<T>() {
        };
        return klass.cast(favorites.get(typeReference));
    }

    public <T> T getFavorite(TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
        Class<T> klass = (Class<T>) typeReference.getType();
        return klass.cast(favorites.get(typeReference));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FavoritesTypeReference f = new FavoritesTypeReference();

        f.setFavorite(String.class, "Java");
        f.setFavorite(Integer.class, 0xcafebabe);
        String s = f.getFavorite(String.class);
        int i = f.getFavorite(Integer.class);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(i);

        // erasure kicks in here, so I can't do it
        // you simply can't make a type token for a generic type.
        // f.setFavorite(List<String>.class, Collections.emptyList());

        f.setFavorite(new TypeReference<List<String>>() {
        }, Arrays.asList("Java", "Kotlin"));
        List<String> favorite = f.getFavorite(new TypeReference<List<String>>() {
        });
        System.out.println(favorite);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have to do unchecked cast `Class<T> klass = (Class<T>) typeReference.getType();` in `getFavorite` method.

Is there a way to avoid doing this cast?

Or is my solution only way to go?

Comment: The blurb above the answer editor at the bottom of this page asks: „*Know someone who can answer?*“. Yes. I think I might. [*Going by his recent answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63424342), this question sounds like it's right down @davidxxx's alley. Here's to you, dave. TIA.

Comment: As in `return (T) constructor.newInstance();` of your example type `TypeReference`, you will have to cast, but I think you can be a tiny bit more elegant: `return (T) favorites.get(typeReference);`. Unless you pollute your `FavoritesTypeReference`in some form, this should be safe enough.

Comment: „*of your example type `TypeReference`...can be a tiny bit more elegant: `return (T) favorites.get(typeReference)`*“ — @TreffnonX? I think I'm missing something. Do you mean replace _`return (T) constructor.newInstance()`_ with _`return (T) favorites.get(typeReference)`_ as the return stmt of _`TypeReference.newInstance( )`_? I don't see an instance of _`favorites`_ anywhere in _`TypeReference`_. So where would _`TypeReference.newInstance( )`_ get the reference to that map your _`return (T) favorites.get(typeReference)`_ is intended to be calling? Or am I overlooking something somewhere. TIA.

Comment: No I meant replace `Class<T> klass = (Class<T>) typeReference.getType(); return klass.cast(favorites.get(typeReference));` with `return (T) favorites.get(typeReference);`.

Comment: „_replace...return klass.cast(...); with return (T)...`_“ — Ahh! Thx for bearing with me, @TreffnonX. I  [*just learned that idiom last week*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399325/call-aws-batch-meter-generic-api). And I've only used it once since. So do I understand correctly, that there's no *semantic* no *effective* no *technical* difference between the two idioms? If so, then would the deciding factor between one or the other be the difference between one dev's subjective definition of „*elegance*“ and the next dev's definition? A choice of *personal preference* in other words? TIA

Comment: @deduper Maybe it is personal preference, but it is different in semantics. The elaborate version casts the class AND the object, where the smaller only ever casts the object. As the class is bound to the object type, it seems ok to do it, unless someone modifies the map in a previously undefined way. Also: One is a compile time cast and one is dynamic. Both are validated at runtime, but one is better optimized (the one with only the object cast). It is ultimately inconsequential which one is used, if we are talking about low frequency-calling.

Answer (score 0):

After additional trial and error I realized it is either `Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites` or `Map<TypeReference<?>, Object> favorites`.

The final example I came up with is:

```
public class FavoritesTypeReference {

    private final Map<TypeReference<?>, Object> favorites = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void setFavorite(TypeReference<T> typeReference, T thing) {
        favorites.put(typeReference, thing);
    }

    public <T> T getFavorite(TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
        if (typeReference.getType() instanceof Class) {
            Class<T> klass = (Class<T>) typeReference.getType();
            return klass.cast(favorites.get(typeReference));
        } else {
            Class<T> klass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) typeReference.getType()).getRawType();
            return klass.cast(favorites.get(typeReference));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FavoritesTypeReference f = new FavoritesTypeReference();

        TypeReference<String> stringTypeReference = new TypeReference<String>() {
        };
        TypeReference<Integer> integerTypeReference = new TypeReference<Integer>() {
        };

        f.setFavorite(stringTypeReference, "Java");
        f.setFavorite(integerTypeReference, 0xcafebabe);
        String s = f.getFavorite(stringTypeReference);
        System.out.println(s);
        int i = f.getFavorite(integerTypeReference);
        System.out.println(i);

        TypeReference<List<String>> listStringsTypeReference = new TypeReference<List<String>>() {
        };
        f.setFavorite(listStringsTypeReference, Arrays.asList("Java", "Kotlin"));
        List<String> listStrings = f.getFavorite(listStringsTypeReference);
        System.out.println(listStrings);
    }
}
```

`getFavorite` method needs to distinguish between classes and parametrized types and casts are necessary.

Comment: What would happen, if you put an instance of a record in your favorites map?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your question. There is main method where records are created.

Comment: References are created. I ask about Records as they are in the preview for JDK14/15: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359 . I think your code might not work with those. (This is speculation though)